# Why Eclipse does not displaying UTF-8 chars

Tags: java, json, eclipse, character-encoding, utf

I am using eclipse Luna and when I try to get json result which includes burmese language on it, am getting strange chars like:

[image]

My code:

```
        InputStream is  = connection.getInputStream();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, sw,"UTF-8");
        String s=sw.toString();
        JSONObject mainjobj= new JSONObject(s);
```

What did I try so far ?..

- I did this: Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types
- and this:  Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8"

But these two didn't work for me.

What is your suggestion about this ?

Comment: What font is the details view using in the preferences?

Comment: Because you haven't told it to use an adequate font.

Comment: @drrob 'Consolas' font -default I think-

Comment: @bmargulies so how can I tell this ?

Comment: Sorry I asked about wrong font should be details view I think (edited my comment). Still Consolas?

Comment: Consolas definitely has limited language glyphs. Maybe this can help http://www.myanmarlanguage.org/note/fixed-width-font-burmese-programming

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a font issue; most fixed width fonts (including Consolas) do not support Burmese glyphs as they cannot be correctly rendered fixed width.

See: http://www.myanmarlanguage.org/note/fixed-width-font-burmese-programming